# How to set labels in Grafana with ClickHouse

Tags: grafana, clickhouse

I use Grafana + ClickHouse to monitor logs. A have a "Logs" widget made from clickhouse sql query. When I switch on "Unique labels" option I see that no unique labels in the strings:
[image: No unique labels]

My sql query is simple:

```
SELECT  "timestamp", "message", "level", "source", "event", "job", "traceId", "stack", "url", "payload" FROM "logs"."services" WHERE   ( timestamp  >= $__fromTime AND timestamp <= $__toTime ) AND source in (${source}) AND ( level IN ('warn', 'error' ) ) order by "timestamp" desc LIMIT 1000
```

How can I add labels to the log items?

Comment: Have you tried returning labels as a json (something like loki does it)? Something like this: `{"label1": "value1", "label2": "value2"}`.

Comment: @markalex Tried to query ```SELECT '{"label1": "value1", "label2": "value2"}' as labels, "timestamp",  "message", ...``` with no result - this field does not recognized as labels.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution to add labels, instead I added this information to the second parameter (in your case "message") using concat(s1, s2, ...). This will give you the same visual experience :)
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/string-functions#concat

Example in your scenario:
SELECT  "timestamp", concat('- ', level , ' - ' , message)) as log_msg, "level", "source", ...
Should produce: "2023-09-19 14:30:32.00 - ERROR - integrationServiceError..."

Comment: This is one of solutions, thanks!